# How to make a loop of number of lists as argument to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

I need to define a loop that directs below mentioned dataframe/series i.e. (x1, x2, x3,...., x7) as an argument 'x' (one df/series at a time) to **linear_regression** function. 'y' argument of the function remains same. Only the x input should be changed to x1, x2, x3 and so on.

```
x1 = lr_dataset3[['channel_app', 'channel_mobile', 'channel_others', 'channel_pc', 'channel_wechat']]
x2 = lr_dataset3['quantity']
x3 = lr_dataset3['type_x']
x4 = lr_dataset3['promise']
x5 = lr_dataset3['original_unit_price']
x6 = lr_dataset3['final_unit_price']
x7 = lr_dataset3['direct_discount_per_unit']

y = lr_dataset3['ordered_unordered']

def linear_regression(x, y):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    reg = LinearRegression()
    if x.ndim == 1:
        x1 = scaler.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1, 1))
        result_log = sm.OLS(y, x1).fit()
        return result_log.summary()

    else:
        scaler.fit(x)
        x1 = scaler.transform(x)
        result_log = sm.OLS(y, x1).fit()
        return result_log.summary()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i just rephrased my question, please check now. I need to make a loop.

Comment: `for x in [x1,x2,x3,x4,...]: linear_regression(x,y)`.?? .. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements